# Typescript: Is there a way to check if a variable is an interface-defined object with nested properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings, typechecking

For example:

```
interface TEST_OBJECT {
    "test1" : TEST_TYPE;
    "test2" : TEST_INTERFACE
}

type TEST_TYPE = string|number;

interface TEST_INTERFACE {
    "test3" : boolean;
}
```

Is there a way to check if a variable is a TEST_OBJECT?

Comment: You may be looking for [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), aside from that, I'm not aware of any other options since there is no way to runtime check an interface.

Comment: thanks, i looked at it, and it seems like it's best used for a single top-level property, and would be a messy for multiple nested properties

Comment: if object is not made by constructor only one way to check is `if (variable.test1 !== undefined && variable.test2 !== undefined)`. If it is you can chcek by instanceof `if (variable instanceof TEST_OBJECT)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for TypeScript to *automatically* provide runtime type guards for you, that's not possible.  In practice though, the compiler is pretty good at narrowing types for you, depending on how much you know about the object you're inspecting.  For example, say you have something you know is either a `TEST_OBJECT` or a `string`:

```
function hasKey<K extends string>(k: K, x: any): x is Record<K, {}> {
  return k in x;
}

declare const obj: TEST_OBJECT | string;

if (hasKey("test2", obj)) {
  // it knows that obj is a TEST_OBJECT now
  console.log(obj.test1);
  console.log(obj.test2.test3 === false); 
} else {
  // it knows that obj is a string
  console.log(obj.charAt(0));
}
```

If you have no idea what the object you're inspecting might be, then, as @JoshCrozier said, [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) are probably the way to go.  It's possible to build these up the same way you've built up your interfaces and types:

```
function hasKey<K extends string>(k: K, x: any): x is Record<K, {}> {
  return k in x;
}

function isTEST_INTERFACE(x: any): x is TEST_INTERFACE {
  return hasKey("test3",x) && (typeof x.test3 === 'boolean');
}

function isTEST_TYPE(x: any): x is TEST_TYPE {
  return (typeof x === 'string') || (typeof x === 'number');
}

function isTEST_OBJECT(x: any): x is TEST_OBJECT {
  return hasKey("test1", x) && isTEST_TYPE(x.test1) &&
    hasKey("test2", x) && isTEST_INTERFACE(x.test2);
}

// use it:
declare const obj: TEST_OBJECT | string
if (isTEST_OBJECT(obj)) {
  console.log(obj.test1);
  console.log(obj.test2.test3 === false); 
} else {
  console.log(obj.charAt(0));
}
```

Hope that helps.